# ffmpeg shell script globbing

Tags: shell, ffmpeg, glob

I have a pretty straight forward question.  I have a bunch of individual directories that are labeled as `./001 ./002 ... ./201`
within each directory contains files that have the identifier `*_IO.PNG`

I can use the shell command: `ffmpeg -framerate 20 -pattern_type glob -i './066/*IO.PNG' -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p 066.mp4` and this works great.  It does exactly what I want.

However, I tried to write a shell script, which is below but this does not work.  It seems to be loading individual files instead of all of them at once.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
 #!/bin/bash
 for i in {1..5}
 do
   FILE=$(printf %03d $i)
   echo " This file: $FILE"
   infile='./$FILE/*IO.PNG'
   echo $infile
   ffmpeg -framerate 20 -pattern_type glob -i $infile -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p './$FILE.mp4'
 done
```

Comment: Shell variables don't expand in single quotes.

Comment: With double quotes, this problem remains.

Comment: You aren't showing any errors. **How** is this not working? Though at a guess I'm going to assume that using `-i "$infile"` will solve the problem by preventing the shell from expanding the glob (and thus letting `ffmpeg` handle it).

Comment: Thank you Etan.  I apologize for being snarky.  That did work.  So what did putting quotes around `$infile` do?

Comment: Run `infile='./$FILE/*IO.PNG'; printf '[%s]\n' $infile; echo ====; printf '[%s]\n' "$infile"` and see for yourself.